# UITableView performance issues when adding UIViews to cell.contentView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am experiencing performance problems when using some subviews on my `UITableViewCells`. After I keep scrolling it eventually starts getting very slow.

First step I am doing is creating a common `UIView` for every cell, essentially this is creating a white cell with a rounded effect on the cell with a shadow.  The performance for this seems to be normal so I don't think it's the culprit.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *NewsCellIdentifer = @"NewsCellIdentifier";


       NewsItem *item = [self.newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];


                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,100)];
                whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
                whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
                whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
                whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

                [cell.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
                [cell.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];

                cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
                cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
                cell.layer.opaque = YES;

                cell.opaque = YES;    
            }

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self NewsItemThumbnailView:item]];

            return cell;
}
```

Here is the method that returns the thumbnail view of the graphic and text:

```
- (UIView *) NewsItemThumbnailView:(NewsItem *)item
{
    UIView *thumbNailMainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 70)];
    UIImageView *thumbNail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.ThumbNailFileName]];
    thumbNail.frame = CGRectMake(10,10, 45, 45);
    UILabel *date = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    date.frame = CGRectMake(10, 53, 45, 12);
    date.text = item.ShortDateString;
    date.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    date.textColor = [BVColors WebDarkGrey];
    CGFloat fontSize = 10.0;
    date.font = [BVFont Museo:&fontSize];

    date.opaque = YES;
    thumbNail.opaque = YES;
    thumbNailMainView.opaque = YES;


    [thumbNailMainView addSubview:thumbNail];
    [thumbNailMainView addSubview:date];

    return thumbNailMainView;
}
```

The performance problem seems to be when I add the thumbnail view to the cell because when I comment that line out, I don't seem to have it. The thumbnail information is dynamic and will change with each cell. I would appreciate any advice on how I should do this without degrading the performance.

Comment: By adding a subview every time this code is called you are growing the collection of subviews in the UITableViewCell.  The dequeing function creates a new table view cell or grabs an existing.  Once it starts grabing existing cells, you are adding a UIImageView overtop of the existing UIImageView.  The result is you will exponentially increase the UIImageViews that need to be rendered for each cell.  This will slow your app down substantially.  I like jszumski answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up leveraging a solution found on this stackoverflow post:

[How should I addSubview to cell.contentView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490433/how-should-i-addsubview-to-cell-contentview)

Essentially when the cell is first initialized I am setting the view as mentioned by Nishant; however once the cell is reused I am extracting out the items I need to change, such as an UIImageView and then a UILabel.  Since these are pointers I can modify just what I need when I need to and the performance is fast again. Here is a abbreviated version of what I did.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *NewsCellIdentifer = @"NewsCellIdentifier";

    NewsItem *item = [self.newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];


    UIView *thumbNailMainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 70)];
    UIImageView *thumbNail;

    UIView *textMainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,80,80)];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(52,-5, 70, 20)];
    UILabel *teaserLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,20, 210, 40)];

    UIView *newsItemCornerMainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(255.7, 55.2, 55, 55)];
    UIImageView *cornerIconView;

    // If the cell doesn't existing go ahead and make it fresh.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:NewsCellIdentifer];


        // Configure all the various subviews

         .....   //Sample below

        // Make the title view
        headerLabel.text = item.Title;
        CGFloat textfontSize = 16.0f;
        headerLabel.font = [BVFont Museo:&textfontSize];
        headerLabel.textColor = [BVColors WebBlue];
        headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        headerLabel.tag = 50;
        // Make the Teaser view
        teaserLabel.text = item.Teaser;
        teaserLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        CGFloat tfontSize = 13.0f;
        teaserLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        teaserLabel.textColor = [BVColors WebDarkGrey];
        teaserLabel.font = [BVFont HelveticaNeue:&tfontSize];
        [teaserLabel sizeToFit];
        teaserLabel.tag = 51;
        [textMainView addSubview:headerLabel];
        [textMainView sendSubviewToBack:headerLabel];
        [textMainView addSubview:teaserLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textMainView];

        ....
    }

    thumbNail = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:47];
    [thumbNail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.ThumbNailFileName]];

    headerLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:50];
    headerLabel.text = item.Title;
    teaserLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:51];
    teaserLabel.text = item.Teaser;

    cornerIconView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:48];
    [cornerIconView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.CornerIconFileName]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`UITableView` will call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` each time a cell comes into view, and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will reuse existing cell objects if they are available.  These two facts combine to put you in a scenario where every time you scroll, the same finite number of cell objects end up with an increasing number of subviews.

The proper approach is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that has a property for `thumbnailView`.  In the setter for that property, remove the previous thumbnail (if any) and then add the new one to the `contentView`.  This ensures that you'll only ever have one thumbnail subview at any time.

A less optimal approach would be adding a tag to the `UIView` returned from `NewsItemThumbnailView` (`thumbNailMainView.tag = someIntegerConstant`) and then searching for any view with that tag and removing it before adding another:

```
 // remove old view
 UIView *oldThumbnailView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:someIntegerConstant];
 [oldThumbnailView removeFromSuperview];

 // add new view
 [cell.contentView addSubview:[self NewsItemThumbnailView:item]];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful on leading me to a final solution!

Answer (score 1):

You should change `thumbNailMainView` content only everytime but you should not add its content on cell everytime.

So add this line where you are allocating cell

```
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[self NewsItemThumbnailView:item]];
```

add this inside braces. and then access **thumbNailMainView** from cell and pass that item data which you need to change for each cell.

Assign a tag to `thumbNailMainView` and its subview `thumbNail` then access it as

```
   UIView *_thumbNailMainView =  [cell.contentView viewWithTag:_thumbNailMainView_tag];
UIImageView *_thumbNail =  [_thumbNailMainView viewWithTag:thumbNail_tag];
_thumbNail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:item.ThumbNailFileName];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful on leading me to a final solution!