# UITableViewCell not redrawn properly on scrolling too fast

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am using Auto layout with cells on dynamic height in iOS, and I encountered a very peculiar bug that occurs at random. It seems that at times when I scroll too fast (not all the time though), there is a separator that shows up on the cell as if the height is not calculated fast enough. Can someone point me to the direction of where it may have gone wrong?
This is my code in cellforRowAtIndexPath:
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

```
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366596/uitableview-performance-issues-when-adding-uiviews-to-cell-contentview
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    cell.layer.opaque = true

    cell.opaque = true
```

The images are shown below:
[image: Incorrect Image]

**Here is the correct image:**
[image]

code for calculating height:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 10;

    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366596/uitableview-performance-issues-when-adding-uiviews-to-cell-contentview
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    cell.layer.opaque = true

    cell.opaque = true

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

Comment: Hi how did you added separator  ?

Comment: By the way, I am using sections. So, the spacing is done here:
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

Comment: Hi, can you update code viewForHeaderInsection and cellForRowAtIndexPath ? that will be helpful for me.

Comment: I have added the relevant code. There is no viewForHeaderInsection. Thx for the help.